# Unable to delete directory: apollo-codegen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, graphql

I have some problem with Apollo client on Android which is rebuilding project on ubuntu.
I tried from [this site](https://medium.com/mindorks/what-is-graphql-and-using-it-on-android-ab8e493abdd7) And working well on first rebuilding. So I added new query graphql and I rebuilding again and I get that error.

So far, I was try

1. ./gradlew clean on the terminal
2. Delete folder on the directory
3. rm -rf {mydir}/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen or on superuser

This is my result:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/bon-appety-android/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

If I remove I get like this:

```
rm: cannot remove 'apollo-codegen/': Directory not empty
```

I checked that location with `lsof | grep app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen`

I get like that

```
bash      4663               rachmad  cwd       DIR                8,5     24576     123350 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules
java      7372               rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7373          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7376          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7377          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7378          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7379          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7380          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7381          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7382          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7383          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7384          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7385          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7386          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7387          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7388          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7389          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7390          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7400          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7401          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7408          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
java      7372 7409          rachmad  330r      REG                8,5      5287     126198 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules/apollo-codegen/package.json (deleted)
lsof      9659               rachmad  cwd       DIR                8,5     24576     123350 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules
grep      9660               rachmad  cwd       DIR                8,5     24576     123350 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules
lsof      9661               rachmad  cwd       DIR                8,5     24576     123350 /media/rachmad/Data/PROJECT/myproject/app/build/apollo-codegen/node_modules
```

Answer (score -1):

After wasting time for research this one, I got a simple answer.
just kill that PID.

`kill 7273`